# How can it be shown that $d \leq n-k+1$ in a $[n,k,d]$ linear code?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Assuming I have a $[n,k,d]$ linear code, how can it be shown that $d \leq n-k+1$ ?

Comment: [Singleton bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound) is covered in all coding theory texts I've seen.

Comment: Hint: write the generator matrix of the code in systematic form $G = \left[I\mid P\right]$ and stare very hard at that last row of $G$ (which is a codeword, in case you had forgotten). What is the maximum possible weight of this codeword over all possible choices of $P$?